# Vscode keeps changing sort order of import when saving changes

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, ide

I checked out a branch of java code using vscode. Made one little change and when I push it gitlab and create a merge request it shows my change as well as tons of changes in the import statements. So I cut and paste from main branch all the import statements into my branch so it would reflect whats in main branch. Problem is when I save vscode the imports flip all over again. Its annoying because it shows tons of changes. Is there a feature in vscode to turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the import order via the setting `java.completion.importOrder`

[image]

Meanwhile, you can check if you set `Orgnize Import` action in the setting `editor.codeActionsOnSave`

Comment: Thank you! For a fellow newbie like me, in Mac do this
Code > Settings > Settings (select VS code window if this is greyed out) > Search "java.completion.importOrder" > Edit in settings.json

Things inside `java.completion.importOrder` doesn't matter if your goal is to stop rearranging. Just ensure `java.saveActions.organizeImports` is set to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Open User Settings (CTRL+SHIFT+O > Settings) and search for "imports", then uncheck the box labeled "Enabled organize imports action on a document save"

[image]